# How to draw dynamic programming table in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygame, dynamic-programming

What is a good way to draw a dynamic programming such as this one (with the path) in python?
[image: Dynamic programming table]

I have looked online and I see [pygame](http://pygame.org/news.html) but is that really the best option for this sort of technical drawing?

One option might be to use matplotlib using something like

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.figure()
col_labels=['col1','col2','col3']
row_labels=['row1','row2','row3']
table_vals=[[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33]]

the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
                  colWidths = [0.1]*3,
                  rowLabels=row_labels,
                  colLabels=col_labels,
                  loc='center right')
plt.text(12,3.4,'Table Title',size=8)

plt.show()
```

How can I draw the line on the table?

Comment: What's wrong with PyGame? The name?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Isn't pygame about interactivity?  I just want to draw a picture.

Comment: Yes, but showing an image is a form of interactivity, limited as it may be.

Comment: It _can_ be, but it doesn't have to. I would maybe try and use matplotlib. Draw some sort of tabular plot with `imshow()`, create custom labels for the axes and then draw that line above all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code yields an approximation of the figure you want, using native Matplotlib tables:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

def get_coord(table, irow, icol):
    # get coordinates of a cell. This seems to work, don't ask why.
    cell = table.get_celld()[irow+1,icol] # row 0 is column headers
    box = cell.get_bbox().get_points() # [[x0, y0],[x1, y1]]
    xc, yc = box.mean(axis=0) # get center
    return xc, yc

col_labels=['G','A','T','C','C']
row_labels= ['G','T','G','C','C']
table_vals= [
    ['x','','','',''],
    ['','','x','',''],
    ['x','','','',''],
    ['','','','x','x'],
    ['','','','x','x']]
line = [(0,0), (0,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)]    

# draw table
the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
    colWidths = [0.1]*len(col_labels),
    rowLabels=row_labels, colLabels=col_labels,
    cellLoc = 'center', rowLoc = 'center', bbox=[.1,.1,.8,.8])
plt.draw() # lay out table, so that cell coordinates are calculated

# look up line coordinates
x = []; y = []
for irow, icol in line:
    xc, yc = get_coord(the_table, irow, icol)
    x.append(xc)
    y.append(yc)

# draw line    
plt.plot(x, y, 'r', linewidth = 5, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlim([0,1])
plt.ylim([0,1])
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: table1]

Note that the result is not extremely beautiful, I could for example not figure out how to change the width of the column with row-labels. There is also the issue that the table is drawn in 'figure coordinates', while the line is drawn in 'data-coordinates', so if you zoom in the line and the table no longer overlap. I struggled for quite some time with these tables, but in my opinion they are quite a PITA to work with and the resulting code is hard to understand.

My preferred solution is to just draw the table by hand:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

col_labels=['G','A','T','C','C']
row_labels= ['G','T','G','C','C']
table_vals= [
    ['X','','','',''],
    ['','','X','',''],
    ['X','','','',''],
    ['','','','X','X'],
    ['','','','X','X']]
line = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
    [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])    
ncol = len(col_labels)
nrow = len(row_labels)

# draw grid lines
plt.plot(np.tile([0, ncol+1], (nrow+2,1)).T, np.tile(np.arange(nrow+2), (2,1)),
    'k', linewidth=3)
plt.plot(np.tile(np.arange(ncol+2), (2,1)), np.tile([0, nrow+1], (ncol+2,1)).T,
    'k', linewidth=3)

# plot labels
for icol, col in enumerate(col_labels):
    plt.text(icol + 1.5, nrow + 0.5, col, ha='center', va='center')
for irow, row in enumerate(row_labels):
    plt.text(0.5, nrow - irow - 0.5, row, ha='center', va='center')

# plot table content
for irow, row in enumerate(table_vals):
    for icol, cell in enumerate(row):
        plt.text(icol + 1.5, nrow - irow - 0.5, cell, ha='center', va='center')

# plot line
plt.plot(line[0] + 1.5, nrow - line[1] - 0.5, 'r', linewidth = 5, alpha = 0.5)

plt.axis([-0.5, ncol + 1.5, -0.5, nrow+1.5])
plt.show()
```

with result:

[image: table2]

This looks much nicer, and the code is straightforward to understand. You might want to adjust some line-widths and font-sizes to your own taste, and hide the axis.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You second solution looks great.

Comment: Hey guy, how i can color one square of this table?