# Drawing matrix plot in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib

I have a matrix stored as a list of lists, and two more lists representing the labels for `x` and `y` axes.

```
A = [[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     [3, 3, 0, 7, 9, 2],
     [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]]    
x = ["A", "B", "C", "E", "F", "G"]
Y = ["R", "S", "T"]
```

I want to draw the matrix as a table (like the picture below).

Is it possible in Python?

[image: Matrix]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104785/how-to-draw-dynamic-programming-table-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you can just use the `plt.text` for those purposes. The code below uses it to obtain the result you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
rcParams['font.size'] = 16

A = [[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     [3, 3, 0, 7, 9, 2],
     [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]]
X = ["A", "B", "C", "E", "F", "G"]
Y = ["R", "S", "T"]

m = len(Y)
n = len(X)

plt.figure(figsize=(n + 1, m + 1))
for krow, row in enumerate(A):
    plt.text(5, 10*krow + 15, Y[krow],
             horizontalalignment='center',
             verticalalignment='center')
    for kcol, num in enumerate(row):
        if krow == 0:
            plt.text(10*kcol + 15, 5, X[kcol],
                     horizontalalignment='center',
                     verticalalignment='center')
        plt.text(10*kcol + 15, 10*krow + 15, num,
                 horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center')

plt.axis([0, 10*(n + 1), 10*(m + 1), 0])
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0, 10*(n + 1), n + 2), [])
plt.yticks(np.linspace(0, 10*(m + 1), m + 2), [])
plt.grid(linestyle="solid")
plt.savefig("Table.png", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

And, you get

[image]